# Waiting for an HTTP request in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, request, openweathermap

I know other people have asked this question, and that I need to use callbacks but I'm not quite sure as to how I should integrate them with my code.

I'm using node.js with express to make a website, and on page load I want the site to go and grab the weather, wait for the response and then load the page with it.

My 'WeatherApp' code is as follows:

```js
const config = require('./config');
const request = require('request');

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
 return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
module.exports = {
 getWeather: function() {
  request(config.weatherdomain, function(err, response, body) {
   if (err) {
    console.log('error:', error);
   } else {
    let weather = JSON.parse(body);
    let returnString = {
     temperature: Math.round(weather.main.temp),
     type: weather.weather[0].description
    }
    return JSON.stringify(returnString);
      }
  });
 }
}
```

And my current routing for a page:

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 var weather;
 weather = weatherApp.getWeather();
 res.render('index', {
  title: 'Home',
  data: weather
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix sync and async approach, that's why you get this issues.

I suggest check out this posts to understand difference.

[What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming (in node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336367/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-programming-in-node)

[Synchronous vs Asynchronous code with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858909/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-code-with-node-js)

About your problem. Solution is simple. Add callback

```
getWeather: function(callback) {
    request(config.weatherdomain, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null)
        } else {
            let weather = JSON.parse(body);
            let returnString = {
                temperature: Math.round(weather.main.temp),
                type: weather.weather[0].description
            }
            callback(null, JSON.stringify(returnString));
       }
    });
}
```

And now in route

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
weatherApp.getWeather(function(err, result) {
     if (err) {//dosomething}
     res.render('index', {
        title: 'Home',
        data: weather
      });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Np. Glad to help.